# Celery command line error if django project has name "app"

Tags: celery, django-celery

Is it possible to run the celery command line if your django project is named "app"?

**Django app structure:**

```
|- app
|  |- __init__.py
|  |- settings.py
|  |- celery.py
|- manage.py
```

`__init__.py` and `celery.py` are set up as per the docs: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/django/first-steps-with-django.html

I get the following error `ImportError: No module named celery` when I run `celery --app=app.celery:app worker`. This error does not exist when I rename "app" to something else, but I prefer not to have to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you need install celery package your virtual environments like

```
pip install celery
```

after installing package check your virtual environments celery version

```
celery --version
```

it display the current celery version and **celery --help** it shows like this
[image]